# How can I get taxonomy term name using term slug & post ID using build in WordPress function or class?

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, terms

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT t.name FROM wp_posts p
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tr.object_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id
    WHERE p.id = 1451
    AND t.slug = 'xxx';
```

It gets the term name (`wp_term.name`) using a given post id and slug (`wp_term.slug`).

The SQL query works, but how can I get the slug name by using a built in WordPress function or class?

Comment: Can you please specify what you want exactly? Do you want to get the term name by post id?

Comment: not really. I have variants, and I want to add the slug of the variant to the url. it's done, but after it, I want to get the term name by the post id AND the by the term slug.

Comment: The post ID is irrelevant. You can't have two terms with the same slug but different names based on the post ID. All you need is https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/

Comment: gives back me null. `get_term_by('slug', 'myslug')` or fasle, does not remember, just not works. with my query it works.

Comment: You haven’t provided a taxonomy…

Comment: @JacobPeattie Add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in multiple different ways. Depending on the context, one way may be better than the other ways.

### Using `WP_Term_Query` class:

Most `wp_term` related queries are internally done using the [WP_Term_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/) class. So if you need different options, using this class can be very useful. For example:

```
// all of these arguments are optional
$args = array(
    // object_ids can be a single post id or array of post ids
    'object_ids' => get_the_ID(),
    // taxonomy can be just a single taxonomy string or array of taxonomies
    'taxonomy' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    // if you need only a specific slug
    'slug'  => 'your-slug-here'
);
$term_query = new WP_Term_Query( $args );
foreach( $term_query->get_terms() as $term ) {
    echo "{$term->name} ({$term->taxonomy})";
}
```

### Using `get_the_terms` function:

For theme template files (e.g. `single.php`), [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) function may be more appropriate. It internally uses cache functions, so it's probably more efficient in this context. For example:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'post_tag' );

if( $terms ) {
    $term = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'name', 'slug' );
    if( isset( $term['some-post-tag'] ) ) 
        echo '<h1>' . $term['some-post-tag'] . '</h1>';
    else 
        echo '<h1>No tag found with [some-post-tag]</h1>';
}
```

For this implementation, `wp_list_pluck()` function may be useful, since `get_the_terms()` doesn't support `slug` directly.

### Using `get_term_by` function:

Since each WordPress taxonomy term slug is unique, so basically if you know the slug from some other source, then post ID may not be needed at all. In this case, you may use the [get_term_by](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) function. For example:

```
// $terms = get_term_by( 'slug', 'some-category-slug', 'category' );
$terms = get_term_by( 'slug', 'some-post-tag', 'post_tag' );
if( $terms ) {
    echo $terms->name;
}
```

`get_term_by` function doesn't support post ID, but as I said, you may not need post ID at all.